# list slices equal to the last digit

Tags: python-3.x, slice, zero-padding

I am working on a school project and for that, I am trying to slice a string equal to the last digit of the string, I need to make sure that each slice is of equal length to the last digit, if it not of equal length then I need to add trailing zeroes

Example: "132567093" should be `['132', '567', '090']`
When I try i get `['132', '567', '09']`

This is so far the code I have

```
n = input()
int_n = int(n)
num=int(n)
lastdigit=num%10
s = n[:-1]
print([s[idx:idx+lastdigit] for idx,val in enumerate(s) if idx%lastdigit 
== 0])
```

Comment: for the example one "132567093" should be ['132', '567', '090'], but I get ['132', '567', '09']

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is to use the `zip` clustering idiom with a fill value

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zipl

*digits, length = '132567093'

length = int(length)

print([''.join(t) for t in zipl(*[iter(digits)]*length, fillvalue='0')])
# ['132', '567', '090']

# To sum them together
print(sum(int(''.join(t)) for t in zipl(*[iter(digits)]*length, fillvalue='0')))
# 789
```

You can also use string formatting:

```
s='132567093'
length = int(s[-1])
digits = s[:-1]
format_str = "{{:0<{}}}".format(length) # {:0<3}
print([format_str.format(digits[i:i+length]) for i in range(0, len(digits), length)])
# ['132', '567', '090']
print(sum(int(format_str.format(digits[i:i+length])) for i in range(0, len(digits), length)))
# 789
```

Comment: not for beginners, but nice multiplying the same reference of `iter` :)

Comment: I wish I could take credit, but that pattern's from the [`zip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: funny how difficult it is to put that in one line, without encrypting it, though. `str.format` has left justification but only with spaces when it comes to strings.

Comment: Can't you do `"{:0<3}".format("09")` to get `"090"`?

Comment: erm, yes, true. probably the best way. should have known that, but I didn't. Sorry I can't upvote twice :)

Comment: How would you add those outputs together?( 132+567+090 = 789)

Comment: Replace the outermost `[]` with `sum(map(int, ...))`

Comment: would the code look like this?:   print(sum(map(int(format_str.format(digits[i:i+length]) for i in range(0, len(digits), length)))))

Comment: Sort of.  `map` takes two arguments, a function and an iterable.  We generated the iterable above, so the final code would look like `sum(map(int, (format_str.format(digits[i:i+length]) for i in range(0, len(digits), length))))`

Comment: You could also use `sum(int(format_str.format(digits[i:i+length])) for i in range(0, len(digits), length))`.  All of these should give the same answer though.

Answer (score 1):

To zero-pad on the left, there's a `str.zfill` method.

By reversing the string, applying zero padding and reversing again, you can achieve this

```
print([s[idx:idx+lastdigit][::-1].zfill(lastdigit)[::-1] for idx,val in enumerate(s) if idx%lastdigit== 0])
```

outputs:

```
['132', '567', '090']
```

without `zfill` you can compute the number of characters to add. The formula is ugly but it's faster because it doesn't create 3 strings in the process:

```
[s[idx:idx+lastdigit]+"0"*(max(0,lastdigit-len(s)+idx)) for idx,val in enumerate(s) if idx%lastdigit== 0]
```

Comment: How would you add those outputs together?( 132+567+090 = 789)